# Python Premature end of script headers error

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, cgi, wsgi

I'm running a new python script, and after many trials I've got it running (somewhat).  Here's the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import cgitb

print "Content-type: text/html"
print

print "this is working"
```

It runs great in SSH, but from the browser I get a 500 error. Consulting the error log, I get "Premature end of script header."  I'm running Ubuntu with mod_wsgi, and I believe that I've set up apache2.conf corectly, sites-available/default correctly, and I have the proper permissions and whatnot set correctly.  And, like I said, python runs great in SSH - but I need it to run as a web app.

Any ideas from anyone out there? I've been working on this for two days, and nothing is working.

Comment: add two newlines after the `content-type` declaration.

Comment: Why are you using `mod_wsgi` for a CGI application? You either need to use WSGI in your script, or configure Apache to run it as a CGI script. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html

Answer (score 0):

If this is a wsgi script via mod_wsgi, it should look something like this:

```
def application (env, r):
    body = 'this is working'
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [ ('Content-Type', 'text/html'), ('Content-Length', str (len (body) ) ) ]
    r (status, response_headers)
    return [body]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, everyone.  While looking through Liquid_Fire's link above (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html), I found a bit about suexec running.  I checked it out, and my box was running suexec.  I commented it out, and HOORAY!  IT WORKS!